# Add files to SVN then delete before commit

Tags: svn, undo, delete-file

I guess I was careless.

I added a bunch of files to svn with `svn add`,
then I saw a few files added that I didn't want so I deleted them with `rm`.

Now I can't commit anymore because the commit is missing files. I tried svn cleanup but it didn't help.

My working option now is to manually delete every .svn directory but that seems wrong.

Comment: You can `svn revert` the added files.

Comment: Believe me, you were not being careless. Svn should really be taking care of this for you, but it is not always that smart.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As I understand it you have this situation:

```
$ touch foo
$ svn add foo
A         foo
$ rm foo
$ svn ci
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: 'foo' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

So to fix it do this: (thanks Linus!)

```
$ svn revert foo
Reverted 'foo'
```

or you can do this:

```
$ touch foo
$ svn delete --force foo
```

for each file, and you should be able to check in without problems.

Comment: Didn't realize this actually deleted the file itself, not just the SVN tracking. Be aware that this removes the file from the local directory as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you added a folder with sub-folders and files inside
then you deleted the folder before you commit it.
In this case you can do as the following.

```
$ svn revert <Deleted Folder Name> --depth infinity
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a slightly modified version of @Gonzalo Mateo, which solved my problem.

```
svn st  | grep '!' | sed 's/!M      \(.*\)$/"\1"/' | xargs svn revert --depth infinity
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple directories with multiple files deleted, the following command could help:

```
svn st  | grep '!M' | sed 's/!M      \(.*\)$/"\1"/' | xargs svn revert
```

I recommend first to list the files that are going to be reverted. We can do it by removing the last pipe:  `svn st  | grep '!M' | sed 's/!M      \(.*\)$/"\1"/'`.

Step by step command explanation:

- `svn st` - It lists added and *unproperly deleted* files with `!M` symbol
- `grep '!M'` It finds the lines with `!M`
- `sed 's/!M      \(.*\)$/"\1"/'` This is used to get rid of the `!M` with the spaces. It will also quote the file names so you don't have to worry if files include spaces on them.
- `xargs svn revert` This will revert all files listed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: **This question is nearly three years old.** Also it would be helpfull to elaborate your answer a little bit more. Also note that the output of `svn st` may change without notice which would render your solution useless...

Answer (score 1):

If you `svn add X` a file, but you haven't committed, then later you decide you want to delete that file (and not commit it); you should simply revert you `svn add X` command with `svn revert X`.

It will then "undo" the not yet committed add.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

`svn st  | grep '!' | sed 's/!M      \(.*\)$/"\1"/' | xargs svn revert --depth infinity`

One thing you should note is that the above code only works for the latest additions. So, do another `svn ci` if it gives an error then run the above code again. Then again `svn ci` until you have reverted every problem.

Bonus:
Add an alias (this is for Oh-My-ZSH Zsh Shell)

`# SVN revert everything like reset hard
alias sra="svn st  | grep '!' | sed 's/!M      \(.*\)$/"\1"/' | xargs svn revert --depth infinity"`

Now `sra` i.e. **SVN Revert All** will make your life easy.